# Functional replacement of springboot routing/mapping to camel endpoints in OSGI

Tags: apache-camel, osgi

Spring boot offers the capability to develop interactive web apps using websockets communication with a browser based client (JavaScript UI). The stomp protocol is used on websockets and then mapped to activemq queues or topics, allowing server side components to interact with a web client through the queues or topics and not through websockets. See spring boot page: https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/ for details. Normal JMS queues/topics on the server side are mapped to ‘N’ number of user specific websocket endpoints (see http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-message-flow
).

Camel seems to have all the necessary components to achieve the same thing:
•   AHC-WS – Camel websocket client
•   Atmosphere-websocket - websocket server
•   Websocket - websocket client/server
•   Stomp -  talks stomp to activemq broker
but has nothing prebuilt and that handles the mappings between user stomp/websocket sessions and individual server side topics and queues.
We are running in an OSGI container and need to duplicate the spring boot websocket (i.e. org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.*) capability but without spring due to the difficulties of supporting Springboot in OSGI. Can anyone suggest an existing example project or strategy to achieve this goal? This is a migration of an existing project and we must continue to support stomp on the websocket side.

Comment: Please give an example of your code, along with what you expected the result to be compared with the actual result. If you can't do that then you probably don't have a suitable question for the StackOverflow site.

Comment: Isn't camel websocket component enough?